# How to predict the new image by using model.predict?

Tags: keras

I have built a model and saved its weights as 'first_try.h5' but I am not able to load the model & run it on any random image. My problem is how to use model.predict_generator or model.predict or model.predict_on_batch methods. I have read the documentation, but I need one small example to do so. Sorry, I am new to this. It is a binary classifier.

I am using CNTK as my backend. I am following this [tutorial.](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)

Need little help.

EDIT: 
I am trying the following way, but the output is just [[0.]]

```
model.load_weights('first_try.h5')
img = Image.open("data/predict/T160305M-0222c_5.jpg")
a = array(img).reshape(1,512,512,3)
score = model.predict(a, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
print(score)
```

Comment: We cannot help you if you do not provide us with a minimal working example or at least with the error message?

Comment: I am following the exact tutorial. I just added few lines which I mentioned above. And I am getting [[0.]] as my output, there is no error, but the output seems to be incorrect.